# How do I clear my progress on Clash Royale?

Tags: android, clash-royale, google-play-games

I've got an old Clash Royale save game on Google Play Games that I would like to overwrite. Most games will let you do this but for some reason Clash Royale won't let you do that. How can I overwrite this with my current save game. And I don't want to use Facebook, only Google Play.

Here's a better explanation:

I've got a save game on my GPG Account. But I've got my current game on my device, not connected to my GPG Account. I would like to put my current game onto Google Play, and delete my old game.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-royale/?s=my-account&f=save-your-progress-with-google-play, you can switch to your current game without interfering with your saved one. However, deleting the saved game won't be possible, it seems.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you have two options:

- Create a new Google account, allowing you to create a new Clash Royale profile. To do so, you must first disable the Google Play sign-in option from the Settings menu, and then erase its data cache from your device's apllications menu. Then a new account should be created. Link it to your other Google account.
- Ask those in Help & Support to erase your progress. To do so, you must go to any help topic and press "No" on the "Was it helpful?" question. Then press "Contact us". Specify that you want for your account to be deleted. A player tag, name, and maybe even ID may be needed. Then, wait some time, and after it gets deleted just re-enter the game and start playing from the beggining on the same Google account.

*The second method is not guaranteed to work, especially if you are a high level  player.*

Comment: I'll try the second method

Comment: According with their FAQ, second method will not work - https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-royale/?s=my-account&f=how-do-i-reset-my-account&p=ios

Comment: @nwildner What if I was to ask Google about deleting the save game?

Comment: Google or Facebook are just used as a Single Sign On platform to your account. The entity that really holds your "saves" and details about your accounts is Supercell. They use your google information as login and that is all.

Answer (score -2):

Just uninstall clash royal and when the app asks if you want to use the saved game you had before you put no.